# How to pass php variable into js event window.location

Tags: php, javascript

I want to redirect the user in the current page view after updating. Please see my codes. please help me to solve this issue. I am not familiar with JavaScript.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'var myvar = $currString ';
echo 'alert("Cash fund has been updated"); window.location = "../cashfund.php?terminalid='+myvar+'"';
echo '</script>';
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You probably need quotes around your $currString

```
 echo 'var myvar = "'.$currString.'";';
```

Then, your location set string will need to order the quotes properly:

```
 echo 'alert("Cash fund has been updated"); window.location = "../cashfund.php?terminalid="+myvar;';
```

Comment: in the landing page? yes.

Comment: Can you paste the generated Javascript code here from browser view>source?

Comment: wait Mr. Joe, I think I have a problem in my $currString. will update you,. thanks

Comment: heres the code in pagesource <script type="text/javascript">var myvar = "G1D9"alert("Cash fund has been updated"); window.location = "../cashfund.php?terminalid="+myvar;</script>

Comment: Sorry - I added the semicolon later. Semicolon after "'.$currString.'"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">\n';
$currString = "yo";
echo 'var myvar = ' . json_encode($currString) . '\n';
echo 'alert("Cash fund has been updated");\nwindow.location = "../cashfund.php?terminalid=" + myvar ';
echo '</script>';
```

json_encode should put the quotes in there for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for this purpose, as JSON is for the most part a subset of JavaScript:

```
$url = '../cashfund.php?terminalid=' . urlencode($myvar);
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'alert("Cash fund has been updated");';
echo 'window.location = ' . json_encode($url, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP) . ';';
echo '</script>';
```

The `JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP` is to avoid generating invalid HTML (and prevent cross-site scripting should the document ever be parsed according to XML or XHTML rules).